Correct usage with commas around names and indefinite articles

In the mid-nineteenth century, Susan B. Anthony and her acquaintance Elizabeth Cady Stanton became two of the leading figures in the women’s rights movement.
Anthony and Stanton travelled across the United States,advocating for female suffrage.
Here, the name Elizabeth Cady Stanton is essential because the reference to Stanton in the following sentence does not make sense otherwise. In addition, the most logical implication is also that Stanton was one of Susan B. Anthony’s acquaintances rather than her only acquaintance.
(https://thecriticalreader.com/commas-names-titles/)

If you wrote 'an acquaintance, Elizabeth Cady Stanton,' would that change the meaning of the second sentence requiring changes?
In the sense that the point of reference is being non-specific when an indefinite article is added, strictly speaking.
Are there any instances where an indefinite article (a, an) preceding a name would be non-restrictive and not require commas as they are not mentioned in the resource?
Grammatically, there are various ways of describing what’s going on. One helpful set of terms is essential vs. nonessential. When the identifier makes sense in the sentence by itself, then the name is nonessential and you use a comma before it. Otherwise, no comma. That explains an exception to the only-thing-in-the-world rule: when the words “a,” “an” or “some,” or a number, come before the description or identification of a name, use a comma.
https://archive.nytimes.com/opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/21/the-most-comma-mistakes/
This distinction is not mentioned in critical reader article and is relevant to discussion.

Writing "an acquaintance, Elizabeth Cady Stanton" doesn't change the general meaning of the sentence. Writing it that way makes the identity of the acquaintance a parenthetical, suggesting that it's less important who she was.
If that were the intent, the second sentence would probably say "Anthony and her acquaintance" rather than "Anthony and Stanton".
But Stanton was actually an important historical figure in the fight for women's suffrage, so the actual text gives her almost equal billing as Anthony in both sentences.

No, there's no connection between the use of commas or "an" vs "her" in the first sentence, and the use of "Stanton" in the second. The article simply said that you need to mention which Stanton is being discussed before you abbreviate her name like that.

In the sense that the point of reference is being non-specific when an indefinite article is added, strictly speaking.

No, what you have are multiple references to the same thing. It's not true that the underlying reference is non-specific. It's very specific! This is an individual that's in history textbooks!
I can't think of any example of the type "an aquaintance, Their Name" where you could leave out the comma, no.
